# mysql distinct with where doesn't work the way I want

Tags: mysql

That is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `row` FROM `parts` WHERE `wall` = '1' ORDER BY `row`
```

That is an answer to the query:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

It looks like if the statement WHERE `wall` = '1' was ignored, because the result is the same as if I made such query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `row` FROM `parts` ORDER BY `row`
```

I want the first query give me
`1 3 4 9 19` (these are the "rows" where "wall" really =1)
I have read some posts about similar issues, still I can't find the solution

[The schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5cb1)

Comment: What does your database schema look like? Is row a column?

Comment: is `wall` in the same table of `row`?

Comment: yes, it is. and wall too:
 id  wall  row place  long  proportion  shapeid  projid  quantity  rwall  rrow  rplace  status  barcode position

Comment: and yes, it is same table as row

Comment: do you care for a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: i've never used this sevice, here is code for creating the table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdc68/1

Comment: make two or three insertions, just enough to reproduce the error you're having

Comment: @user1890184 you only have `wall = '1'` in your example; so, all the values from `row` will be returned. You must add rows enough to reproduce the error you're having.

Comment: @user1890184 try to execute the following: `mysqldump -u <user> -p <password(type it after pressing enter)> <database_name> <table_name> > mydb_tables.sql`; then, copy the part of the table that reproduces the error and update the url of the fiddle in your post.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb7cd did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my own sample data and got the correct results. I copied everything posted on SQL Fiddle to my local mysql database. And queried everything with phpmyadmin and everything worked. This a SQL query to insert data into your database.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `wall`, `row`, `place`, `long`, `proportion`, `shapeid`, `projid`, `quantity`, `rwall`, `rrow`, `rplace`, `status`, `barcode`, `position`) VALUES
(1, '1', 5, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(2, '10', 1, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(3, '1', 2, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(4, '3', 20, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(5, '1', 40, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(6, '2', 4, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(7, '1', 1, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(8, '5', 1, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(9, '1', 13, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
(10, '10', 13, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '');
```

Comment: hm, it really works on Fiddle, but doesn't work where I test this code :(

Comment: Oh, did you swap table 'table' for your own table 'parts'? Your need to do that because your database doesn't have a table called table but 'parts.

Comment: Could you make a new table in mysql with the same structure. And the run my query. Maybe the problem is that mysql doens't accept that you insert data into a table that is already filled with data. In that case your should use an update query instead.

Comment: Your table already has values in it. It works in FIDDLE so the code is correct. Your data my be the problem. Try to do this. Remove the ID value and insert a '' instead, like so. INSERT INTO `parts` (`id`, `wall`, `row`, `place`, `long`, `proportion`, `shapeid`, `projid`, `quantity`, `rwall`, `rrow`, `rplace`, `status`, `barcode`, `position`) VALUES
('', '1', 5, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', ''),
('', '10', 1, 0, 0, '', 0, '', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, '', '');

Comment: This is a game of trial and error. And I am just helping you find your answer.

Comment: It seems you are right, your code works even in my own database. I tried change id from null to '' in my real tabe, but didn't help(

Comment: You know that the SQL query works when you insert it into SQL Fiddle. You didn't provide a link with data, so I think that you have executed the SQL code in a clean table in Fiddle. Then executed your own query. The difference between your own local table and the Fiddle table is that your own table does have data.This data doesn't get overwritten when you execute the query above. The result is that the query on the local database gives the your old wrong result and on Fiddle the correct result. Now good luck and accept my answer.

Comment: Why would you change id from null to ''? I used '' because I didn't know the exact number of rows in you table. When you use '' the next insert will append the number that is already in your table. E.g. if the last number for ID is 50 then the next insert will be 51. If you use 50 for ID value in your insert SQL then mysql doesn't except this because there is already a primary key with 50. The ID column in your table is the primary key and that is an unique identifier for your row. The null you are referring has probably to do with the format of you ID field.

Comment: Could you accept my answer. My reputation was downgraded by my answer below so I could do with an upgrade. ;-)

Comment: my problem is still not solved. I made a new table in my daatabase, inserted your values and my query worked fine with this database. But it doesn't work properly with real database. Here is the dump: http://logproj.500mb.net/parts.sql

Comment: I get the same result as you wrong query output. However it seems to be the correct answer. You have 46 rows where the value of the wall column is 1. (SELECT `row` , `wall` FROM `parts` WHERE `wall` = 1 ORDER BY `parts`.`row` ASC). Then the next step is to look for the distinct 'row' column values. 19 rows are the result. There are in total 1-19 rows. Therefore you get the same result if you look for number of distinct row columns.

Comment: I think that your missing a field or your field data in you table is not correct. I suggest to put you query in words in a logical order and check the data.

Comment: Found the problem. The problem - i'm stupid) There really were 19 results. Anyway, thanks you for help)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps leave out the ''. The difference that you are querying string values instead of numerical values.

Comment: he uses a varchar for `wall`; i guess using `'1'` for comparison is fine.

Comment: no, I've already tried. That is not a problem. And yes, wall is varchar.

Comment: hm, i cant write in comments above(
But i did make three insertions

Comment: @user1890184 you must add the new url; add it as an edit to your question

Comment: Hi, I added sample data to you database.  And I do get different data when using you query.

Comment: hm, there is not enough fields to show, i wouldn't add more, because its hard (my insert is dinamicle). But I can tell for example, if i make a query
SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE `wall` = '1' ORDER BY `row`
It returns me [row: 1 - 13] in phpmyadmin. And its normal.

Comment: Have you added a space before your values in your row 'wall'?

Comment: I didn't understand question, sorry. But I make the very same query as I wrote at the start of the topic.